# PowerPoint 2007 VBA - Unable to Get Ribbon Button Working

Tags: vba, powerpoint, ribbon, ribbon-control, powerpoint-2007

Starting today, no custom button in my PowerPoint 2007 ribbon will work. Each time I click the button, the following error message appears: "The macro cannot be found or has been disabled because of your security settings."

I've Googled this issue to death and found no solution. I'm at a complete loss.

Here is the code for the macro:

```
Sub RunThisCode()<br>
     MsgBox "Yes, this works", vbExclamation
End Sub
```

I've tried both with and without the ByVal control as IRibbonControl. No luck either way.

And the XML code

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
<ribbon>
    <tabs>
        <tab idMso="TabHome">
            <group id="CustomGroup" label="MyGroup">
                <button id="btnTest" label="TestButton" imageMso="HappyFace" size="large" onAction="RunThisCode" keytip="S" />
            </group>
        </tab>
    </tabs>
</ribbon>
```

My installation is running through Softricity SoftGrid as a virtual installation, for what it's worth.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was a compiling error in my code that, oddly, 2007 didn't pick up, but 2010 did. Though, I am still confused why even the basic macro posted above wasn't working.